# Zooming on mobile app causes floated element and text to not center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a fairly straightforward webpage that has a responsive design issue.  It has a floated title bar that takes up 100% of the body width (the entire screen on mobile)

It has text inside it that is supposed to be a centered `<h1>` element with centered text inside it and a "hamburger" nav next to it.

To achieve this I used absolute positioning on the nav, and fixed positioning on the title bar (so that it will stay on top during scroll down).  However, when the user zooms in, everything gets larger so the text bumps into the hamburger nav (essentially just a `div` with a background-image, removed from flow because of absolute positioning) and also gets gets bigger than the screen.  How can I prevent this?

**HTML**

```
    <section class="main firster" id="homeSection">

            <nav id="homeNav">

                <div class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon"></div>

                <ul id="navUl">
                    <li class="mobileShow"><a href="index.html" class="mobileShow">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sleep.html">Sleep</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dine.html">Dine</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><div id="tm">Tierra Magnifica</div></li>
                    <li><a href="relax.html">Relax</a></li>
                    <li><a href="play.html">Play</a></li>
                    <li class="lastList"><a href="party.html">Party</a></li>
                    <li class="contactButton largeHide realContact">Contact Us</li>
                    <li class="navImage largeHide"><img src="media/navMenu.png"></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>

        <div class="tierraDiv about noNav" id="mobileFlag"><p>Tierra <br>Magnifica</p></div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.menuIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2.2em;
    height: 2.2em;
    margin: .2em .2em 0 .4em;
    background: url('../media/nav.png') center;
    border: .15em solid #757170;
    -webkit-border-radius: .4em;
            border-radius: .4em;
}

nav {
    z-index: 30;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul, .mobileNotClicked, nav:hover ul.mobileNotClicked {
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FBF7EE;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 2.6em;
    width: 14em;
}

nav:hover ul, .mobileClicked {
    display: block;
    border-top: .45em solid #9AD5E6;
}

ul #navUl {
    padding: 0;
}

#navUl li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 9em;
    padding: .6em 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757170;
    font-family: "PlantinMTStd-Light";
}

nav li.lastList {
    border: none;
}

nav li.navImage {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

nav li.contactButton {
    margin-top: .3em; 
    width: 9em;
    background: #FBF7EE;
    border: .25em solid #757170;
    font-family: "Gothamer";
}



.menuIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2.2em;
    height: 2.2em;
    margin: .2em .2em 0 .4em;
    background: url('../media/nav.png') center;
    border: .15em solid #757170;
    -webkit-border-radius: .4em;
            border-radius: .4em;
}
```

These pictures should illustrate the issue (although you can't see that the text scrolls of the screen here):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `.tierraDiv` a fixed width (of 150px) and center the `.tierraDiv` with the `margin: 0 auto`. The "auto" will center the 150px wide `.tierraDiv` horizontally in the middle of the page.

Inside the .tierraDiv you have to set the `p` "text-align: center", so that it centers your paragraph (or h1) inside of the 150px.

When you zoom now, your nav-Icon still bumps into the `.tierraDiv` but there is enough space (of the 150px) left, so there is no visual problem any more.

here ist the code you have to add to your provided CSS here:

```
.tierraDiv {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tierraDiv p {
    text-align: center;
}
```